# XE3 TImageList showing same the image on the list on the form

Tags: listview, delphi-xe3, timagelist

I have added 10 BMP files into a `TImageList`. In a `TListView`, I have set the `TImageList` to its `LargeImages` property.

Now the Form is displaying the "first added bmp" 10 times.

Comment: The only way that can happen is if either you added the same image 10 times to the `TImageList`, or all of the `TListItem` objects have the same `ImageIndex` value.

Comment: How do I contol the ImageIndex. I add image this way: ImageList1.Add(BitmapFil, nil);

Comment: [`ImageIndex`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ComCtrls.TListItem.ImageIndex) is a property of `TListItem`. You have to tell each item which image you want it to display from the `TImageList`. How do you expect the `TListView` to know which images to display otherwise?

Comment: I understand - and how do I tell the items which image shall be displayed?

Comment: ListView1.Items[0].ImageIndex := 0;ListView1.Items[1].ImageIndex := 1; Thankyou for your help. Have a nice day!